# Can't create HIVE table with 'ROW FORMAT SERDE'

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a HIVE table with SERDE. But it always fails.

My table creation command -

```
  CREATE TABLE products_info_raw(
    id STRING,
    name STRING,
    reseller STRING,
    category STRING,
    price BIGINT,
    discount FLOAT,
    profit_percent FLOAT
    )
    PARTITIONED BY (
    rptg_dt STRING
    )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
           'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde';
```

I added jar -

```
ADD jar /Users/<user>/Development/Hadoop/projects/e-commerce/hive-json-serde.jar;
```

that contains the necessary JsonSerde class -

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/hadoop/
org/apache/hadoop/hive/
org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/
org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/
org/json/
org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/JsonSerde.class
org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/NewJson.class
org/json/CDL.class
org/json/Cookie.class
org/json/CookieList.class
org/json/HTTP.class
org/json/HTTPTokener.class
org/json/JSONArray.class
org/json/JSONException.class
org/json/JSONML.class
org/json/JSONObject$1.class
org/json/JSONObject$Null.class
org/json/JSONObject.class
org/json/JSONString.class
org/json/JSONStringer.class
org/json/JSONTokener.class
org/json/JSONWriter.class
org/json/Test$1Obj.class
org/json/Test.class
org/json/XML.class
org/json/XMLTokener.class
```

But always keep getting below error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDe
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I am using HIVE 3.1.0.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that jar file was compiled with Hive 3 support?

Comment: No, I downloaded it. Do I need to compile? Can you point me to any instruction link?

Comment: I succeeded by downloading the jar file from another location that I guess supports hive 3.1.0. Thanks.